# Populate in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm new to Node.js and i'm trying to use `populate()`, but it doesn't work for me.

I want to populate `user` with forms

This is the model

```js
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: 'string',
        required: ' Firstname is Required'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: 'string',
        required: ' lastName is Required'
    },
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: ' email is Required'
    },
    phone: {
        type: 'string',

    },
    entrprise: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string',
        required: ' password is Required'
    },
    forms: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Form"
    }

    ]
})
```

and this is the function

```js
const getUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { userId } = req.params;
        if (!userId) return res.status(400).json({ message: "ERROR ID!" });
        const result = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
            .populate('forms')
            .exec()
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Success", result });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "INTERNAL ERROR SERVER!" });
        console.log(err.message);
    }
};
```

but this is what i'm getting as result

```
"message": "Success",
"result": {
    **"forms": [],**
    "_id": "5fc917c49aca9b98b8d9b2aa",
    "firstName": "lea",
    "lastName": "bouteflika",
    "email": "inspirez@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2b$10$zJ5Du2YdfJBsz1ah6JYm7uPe1RYMwmmqmq68TxbvbwYnHVcDKNQeq",
    "phone": "+213556865069",
    "__v": 0
}
```

the forms are empty, does anyone have answer?

Comment: What does the user look like in the database?

Comment: this is the user in the database
{
  forms: [],
  _id: 60290c2609fba7a4482cb3dd,
  firstName: 'lea',
  lastName: 'chaib',
  email: 'leachaib@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$OHmzahuyiFXbqsFE6jWiiul7GOE41J.Rp4z7yA3hQaXG1dceELHw2',
  phone: '77890543321',
  __v: 0
}

Comment: check your db and check the Form collection, is really have the exact spell with Form or another thing like forms, or Forms?  and write the exact name in your userSchema

Comment: i did it but get the same result, empty array, the name of the collection is forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code about populate is correct, you should check the `id` in `forms field` exists in `From` Model, because when you insert data in collection just one collection is updated

```
const listOfIds = await User.findById(userId );
let result = await Form.find({_id: {$in:[listOfIds.forms]}}).lean()
console.log(result)
```

so search list of ids in Form model, if the result is 0 so check the insert query;

and you can use `finById` instead of `finOne`

for a insert new form do like this

```
//1
const form = new Form({
  title
 //....
});
//2
let user = await User.findById(userId); // find the user
//3
let newForm = await form.save(); // save new form
//4
user.forms.push(newForm); // push the new form into user for populate
//5
await user.save(); //update user
```

Comment: thank you, i try to di this but i get an empty array, please can you tell me what do you mean by the insert query?

Comment: put the insert query when you insert forms in collection

Comment: i'm really new in this domain can you please give me an example, i didn't understand

Comment: when you want insert a form in to form collection, after saving you should push the `_id` 
 of inserted form, in to the `user forms` field, after that you can use populate, like the five steps in my answer

Comment: thank you but id didn't work i get the empty array